# Android: buttons alignment

Tags: android

hi i have a hard time making this buttons look good, can i do it normal xml file or should i use styling[image]

below is my xml code

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/cancelbtn"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dip"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="45dip"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Cancel"
        android:textColor="#000000" />
<Button
        android:id="@+id/startbtn"
        android:background=""
        android:textColor="#000000" 
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/fbcancel"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/fbcancel"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dip"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="45dip"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:text="Start" />
```

the start button is big in height and small in width..not able to make exact  as cancel buton

Comment: Were you afraid to post the whole xml layout?

Comment: are you using image as background..?

Comment: @Prashant Mishra..no iam not using any image as background

Comment: android:layout_height="45dip"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"  remove them and then try.

Comment: @Carl Saldanha when i see it in device the start button is way smaller than cancel button and they are not in exact same line

Comment: @Prashant Mishra ..getting foreclose if iam removing the height value

Comment: sory just remove  android:layout_weight="1.0"  and then try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to different number of characters in the Button Text it's showing like this.
you need to give the fixed width and height to the button.

See [this](http://androidv.wordpress.com/2012/08/09/how-to-customize-a-button/) link to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Remove  `android:layout_weight="1.0"` from both buttons and `android:layout_alignTop="@+id/fbcancel"` from start button

Comment: Also, try to make layout_height wrap_content instead of 45 dip

Comment: removing android:layout_alignTop="@+id/fbcancel" makes the start button move to diiferen position

Comment: is size of both buttons same now?

Comment: If yes, add android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" to start button

Comment: no the size oof the buttons are not same, the canel is good but start button is too small half of cancel button

Comment: are you taking about height of cancel button? Try making height of both buttons as wrap content. Remove 45dip from BOTH buttons.

Comment: and also, you have written  android:background="". Try giving some color in this background like  android:background="#0000FF"

Comment: i did removed 45dip added background,added android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" ..still samething..dont know where itz going wrong

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20863/discussion-between-misha-bhardwaj-and-teekib)